# How can I use dlib for a neural network regression?

Tags: c++, neural-network, regression, dlib

It seems that `dlib` needs a loss layer that dictates how the layers most distant to our input layer are treated. I cannot find any documentation towards the loss layers but it seems that there is no way to have just some summation layer.

Summing up all the values of the last layer would be exactly what I need for the regression, though (see also: https://deeplearning4j.org/linear-regression)

I was thinking along the lines of writing a custom loss layer but could not find information about this, either.

So, have I overseen some corresponding layer here or is there a possibility to have what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loss layers in dlib are listed in the menu on dlib's [machine learning page](http://dlib.net/ml.html).  Look for the words "loss layers". There is lots of documentation.

The current released version of dlib doesn't include a regression loss.  However, if you get the current code from github you can use the new loss_mean_squared layer to do regression. See: https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/dlib/dnn/loss_abstract.h